# Python-Qt5 : How do you create variable from QLineEdit?

Tags: python, qt-designer

I need to create a variable from QLineEdit input called 'askkeyword' so I can use it in a function get_list().

```
#Produced in QtDesigner
import json  # <-- added
import csv  # <-- added
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

class Ui_MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):

    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        self.keywordbox = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.widget1)
        self.keywordbox.setObjectName("keywordbox")
        self.verticalLayout_5.addWidget(self.keywordbox)

    def get_list():
        data = aliexpress.get_product_list(['productId', 'productTitle', 'salePrice', 'originalPrice', 'imageUrl'],askkeyword, pageSize='40')
        with open('data.csv', 'w', newline='') as csvfile:
            fieldnames = ['productId', 'productTitle', 'salePrice', 'originalPrice', 'imageUrl']
            writer = csv.DictWriter(csvfile, fieldnames=fieldnames)
            writer.writeheader()
            for product in data['products']:
                productId = product['productId']
                productTitle = product['productTitle']
                salePrice = product['salePrice']
                originalPrice = product['originalPrice']
                imageUrl = product['imageUrl']
                writer.writerow({'productId': productId, 'productTitle': productTitle, 'salePrice': salePrice,
                                 'originalPrice': originalPrice, 'imageUrl': imageUrl})
```

Comment: `askkeyword = self.keywordbox.text()`.

Comment: @ekhumoro  how do I reuse it on get_list() ?

Answer (score 0):

Simply get the text and assign to a variable-

```
var = self.keywordbox.text()
```

To make global varible use

```
self.var = self.keywordbox.text()
```

and use `self.var` anywhere in the code.

Comment: python closes when I do this :

    def get_list(self, askkeyword):
        print(self.askkeyword)
        # global productId
        # askkeyword = input('please enter keyword')
        data = aliexpress.get_product_list(['productId', 'productTitle', 'salePrice', 'originalPrice', 'imageUrl'], self.askkeyword, pageSize='40')